# Can i create array by use php variable in a loop?

Tags: php, arrays

Can I create an array by use php variable in a loop ?

```
<?php
for($i=5;$i<=100;$i++)
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '$i' order by id asc";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $datas=mysql_fetch_array($result);{
    $username = stripslashes(str_replace('\r\n', '<br>',($datas['username'])));
    }
    ${'name' . $i} = $username;
}
?>
```

Okay , Now I have php variable $name1-$name100

And then I want to create array by use php variable $name1-$name100

```
$my_array = array(php variable $name1-$name100);
```

How can I do ?

Comment: Your code hurts my brain.

Comment: Here is proper way to query mysql http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just modify how you store the username:

```
$my_array = array();
for ( $i = 5; $i <= 100; $i++ ) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '$i' order by id asc";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $datas = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $username = stripslashes(str_replace('\r\n', '<br>',($datas['username'])));
    $my_array[] = $username; // push usernames into array
}
```

Also you shouldn't run so many queries, so I suggest something like this:

```
$usernames = array();
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id >= 5 AND id <= 100 ORDER BY id ASC";
$result = mysql_query( $query );

if ( mysql_num_rows( $result ) > 0 ) {
    while ( $data = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) )
        $usernames[] = stripslashes( str_replace( '\r\n', '<br>', $data['username'] ) );
}
```